# How to connect to a network from terminal

Tags: command-line, networking, wireless

I recently updated to 13.10 from 13.04. After rebooting, the system dropped into low graphics mode. I had previously configured a Wireless Broadband connection named "EVDO Connection". How do I connect to this network from terminal?

[note] I tried using LiveCD and then the `chroot` command but then I was unable to make `apt-get` install any updates. It did not detect the internet connection.

Comment: It is preferred if you can post separate questions instead of combining your questions into one. That way, it helps the people answering your question and also others hunting for atleast one of your questions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ubuntu's NetworkManager service can be accessed via a command called `nmcli`. I'm not too sure if it's installed by default, but it seems it is, since it's part of the `network-manager` package.

To connect to a network, you need to know its NetworkManager ID. You can do so by using the following command:

```
nmcli connection
```

This should give you a list similar to this:

```
yjwong@yjwong-laptop:~/Documents/searchagram/build$ nmcli connection
NAME       UUID                                   TYPE              TIMESTAMP-REAL                    
Wong       6944f99a-21d2-4dd9-8ac4-a140e1024970   802-11-wireless   Fri 27 Sep 2013 04:26:04 PM
rpi        8084e8bd-c52c-4954-8721-0dac198604b7   802-11-wireless   Wed 01 May 2013 04:33:58 AM
AndroidAP  bb3e5a13-98e5-46eb-bfb4-c294f8757070   802-11-wireless   Mon 04 Nov 2013 05:01:11 PM
...
```

To bring up the "Wong" connection, simply execute:

```
nmcli connection up Wong
```

If your connection was named "EVDO Connection" you can execute:

```
nmcli connection up "EVDO Connection"
```

Comment: I'm sorry for this delayed a response, but thanks. Your answer worked fine for me.

Comment: I am getting "Connection activation failed: No suitable device found for this connection."

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following command for wireless devices:

```
iwconfig wlan0 essid NETWORK_NAME key WIRELESS_KEY
```

replacing the capital letters with the actual network and key

see the complete guide on [linux.com](http://www.linux.com/learn/tutorials/374514-control-wireless-on-the-linux-desktop-with-these-tools)

the commands you mention (update & upgrade) will update your system and additional software to the latest version, it may or not solve issues you are experiencing.